# find & vbCrLf & within a string - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In a string I have something like "First & vbCrLf & Name" - however, I want to take out the & vbCrLf & so it doesnt cause a line break.

I have done something like

```
If theString.Contains("& vbCrLf &") Then
    ' and replace, could do this above of course, but I just want it to go into the IF
End If
```

and

```
If theString.Contains("\n") Then
    ' and replace, could do this above of course, but I just want it to go into the IF
End If
```

and even `"\r\n"` but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it's "First & vbCrLf & Name" and not "First " & vbCrLf & "Name" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If theString.Contains(vbCrLf) Then
    'Do something
End If
```

Alternatively...

```
theString = theString.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
```

Comment: wow, you won't be surprised to know that I have only started learning VB! will accept when So lets me. Thanks

Comment: It's okay. I think I did the same thing when I was learning it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
If theString.Contains(Environment.NewLine) Then
   ' Code goes here
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the vbCrLf from the string literal in Contains.

```
testVal = testVal.Replace(vbCrLf, String.Empty).Replace("&", String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

Metacharacters not supported by VB.Net for Strings - can be used with RegEx and probably a few other .Net functions.

In your OP I think you intended:

```
If theString.Contains("& vbCrLf &") Then
```

to be

```
If theString.Contains(vbCrLf) Then
```

You can test for and replace in one command:

```
    Dim s As String = vbCrLf
    MsgBox(s.Length)
    s = s.Replace(vbCrLf, "") 
    MsgBox(s.Length)
```

Comment: You may find this useful for text that may have other variations for line ends: 
        s = s.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")